# How Fragments handle touches?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am playing with android's `Fragments` and I found something that didn't make a lot of sense to me.
I am using the compatibility package and testing on a nexus one with 2.3.3 since I don't have a motorola xoom yet.

My issue is:
When I replace a `fragment` with another, the one in the back continues to receive the touches.

Here's the code to reproduce.

I have a list of items and when you press a row a new fragment will be created and shown.
**BUT** if you touch the green fragment, it will be received by the `ListFragment`, increasing the amount of back buttons press I have to make to go back to the `ListFragment`.

Can someone explain why?

EDIT:
As CommonsWare suggested, I deleted the code pasted here since I opened this as an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15537) in the android issue tracker and you can [download](http://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=4647945978246285226&name=Demo2.zip&token=70bce9af3c20a0a1c7c6c219bfe1a197) the demo project from there.

Comment: You might want to ZIP up a complete project that demonstrates the problem and link to it from the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem.  I have a smaller size fragment on top of a larger fragment where you can see the larger fragment sticking out from the smaller one.   In some cases when I press the fragment on top it would trigger the onClick event handler of the fragment on the bottom.

To prevent this from happening I set the onClickListener to the parent layout of the smaller fragment.  By doing this it prevents the onClick event from being passed to the fragment behind it.

```
LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //left empty on purpose to capture the onClick event. 
    }
});
```